# JavaScript Project

Tags: javascript

I am writing a JavaScript page and here are my directions: (code will follow)

- Create a variable named color.  Assign the result of a prompt dialog box as the value for the color variable.
- The prompt dialog box asks the user to select red, white, or blue
- Create a switch statement, the test expression is the color variable converted to uppercase.
- Use RED, WHITE, BLUE after the case keywords.
- As the code executes, reflect back to the user the selected choice.
- Add a default clause that will execute if the user enters a choice other than those offered.
- Remember that the user may click Cancel on the prompt dialog box.  Create code before the switch statement to handle this eventuality.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Project 4 4-29</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var color;

color = prompt("Enter a color of either red, white, or blue");

switch (color){
    case "red":
    alert("RED");
    break;

    case "white:
    alert("WHITE");
    break;

    case "blue":
    alert("BLUE");
}

default: prompt("You have entered a color that is not one of the choices");

</script>
</html>
```

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? Keep in mind that I am new to this so keep it simple for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many problem in your code. `<head>` not closed.there in the second case `case "white:`should be

```
 case "white":
```

the line `default: prompt("You have entered a color that is not one of the choices");` should be inside the switch{}
So you can try this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Project 4 4-29</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var color;

color = prompt("Enter a color of either red, white, or blue");

switch (color){
    case"red":
    alert("RED");
    break;

    case "white":
    alert("WHITE");
    break;

    case "blue":
    alert("BLUE");
    break;

    default: 
    prompt("You have entered a color that is not one of the choices");
}



</script>
<head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that without a `break;` in the `blue` case, enter blue will prompt the user for a color again.

Answer (score 1):

You have here syntax error:

```
  case "white"://<-- you are also missing the closing double quotes.
      alert("WHITE");
    break;
  case "blue":
     alert("BLUE");
   break;//<-- use break to prevent fallback
  default: //<-- put inside switch ... case
     alert("You have entered a color that is not one of the choices");
}
```

Side note, user may also enter the color in upper case so, you can handle it like this:

```
color = prompt("Enter a color of either red, white, or blue");
color = color ? color.toLowerCase() : color;//<-- to lower case, as per your cases
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (color){
case "red":
    ...

default:
    alert("Default");
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would help current and future readers understand this answer even better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop to make sure the user eventually enters a valid color.

JS:

```
var choosing = true;
var color = prompt('Please choose a color: red, white, or blue');

while (choosing) {
    switch (color) {
        case 'red':
            alert('RED');
            choosing = false;
            break;
        case 'white':
            alert('WHITE');
            choosing = false;
            break;
        case 'blue':
            alert('BLUE');
            choosing = false;
            break;
        default:
            color = prompt('You didn\'t enter a valid color. Please choose a color: red, white, or blue');
    }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ln9dc07m/).

Comment: I liked this option and tried it but it wouldn't render in the browser (Chrome)